# c++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr:

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when running:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): basic_string::substr:

I am brand new, any other tips would be appreciated as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int position = 1;
    string letter;

    cout << "Enter in your full name seperated by a space: ";
    getline (cin, name);

    cout << name.substr(0, 1);

    while (position <= name.length())
    {
        position++;
        letter = name.substr(position, 1);

        if (letter == " ")
        {
            cout << name.substr(position + 1, 1) << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Walk through the values `position` can have with a small string on a piece of paper.

Comment: `position + 1` becomes out-of-bounds on the last three iterations. You got a lot to learn, including how to properly iterate over stuff with 0-indexing. Also, if you just want one letter, use `name[position]`. Recommend getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Comment: To iterate over the values in a `string` use a **range-based `for` loop**, like `for( char const ch: name )`. Note that these values are encoding values, which for usual UTF-8 encoding only correspond to characters when those characters are in the ASCII subset. Unfortunately there's no direct support in the C++ library for iterating over *characters*, or for advancing one character, but with UTF-8 this is easy to implement, and for that your approach of representing a character with a string is sensible, and then you'd use an ordinary `for` loop, as you do.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reach an index after the last index, you need to change your loop condition to :
 `position < name.length()`

and you can solve this problem using for-loop which is more used for such problems, you just need to substitute your while-loop with :

```
for (int position = 0; position < (name.length()-1); position++) {
    if (name[position] == ' ') {
        cout << name[position+1];
    }
}
```

Using this you wouldn't need to use `substr()` method neither `string letter` .

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, `position` will increase to a number equal to the characters entered by the user (i.e. "Abc Def" last loop iteration: position = 8). In this case `name.substr(position, 1);` tries to extract the character after the last character in your string, hence the `std::out_of_range` exception.
You may want to change your loop condition to: `while (position <= name.length() - 1)` or `while (position < name.length())`

Comment: That will still be out-of-bounds since he did `name.substr(position + 1, 1)`.

Comment: @FeiXiang It would only be out of bounds, if the input ends with space.

Comment: No, @FeiXiang is right. Also `position++;` takes place after the test.

Comment: @user4581301 No, if the `position` parameter passed to `substr` is equal to the string length, the function returns an empty string. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/). There will be no `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: I see you. Bad idea, but not fatal. The positioning of the ++ is still a problem though.